# Macbook Pro 6.2 (mid 2010) screen is blank

Tags: 16.04, screen, macbook-pro

I have a mid 2010 15" Core i7 Macbook Pro with ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed as the only OS. The OS was working reasonably well for several weeks with the exception of waking when the lid is opened being buggy. However, now the laptop screen does not display anything - the screen is active however (i.e. backlight is on). I am able to ssh into the computer so I know that Ubuntu is running. The external monitor is not recognized either.

I am not sure what caused the problem as I didn't actively make any changes, however I think updates may have been applied shortly before.

This model MacBook Pro has an GeForce GT 330M discrete video card and an Intel HD integrated graphics. The Nvidia drivers are installed and Nvidia kernel module is loaded.

I am unable to get any output on the screen even during boot up nor can I display the GRUB recovery cli, so I am stuck with SSH cli only for making the repairs.

Comment: What happens if you connect an external video monitor? Cheers, Al

Comment: external monitor does not seem to receive a signal at all. backlight remains off and screen goes into power saver mode.

Comment: Try and boot to a Ubuntu Live CD (DVD) and recheck both internal and external video monitors. Cheers, Al

Comment: Pending the results of my prior comment... does this MBP have a user-removable battery? If so, remove it, and then hold down the **power** key for about 5 seconds. Replace the battery and see if it works now. If the battery is non-removable, press **Shift-Control-Option** on the **left side** of the keyboard, then press the **power** button at the same timeLast idea... hold down **command-s** at boot time and see if you get any textual screen output... and later try holding down the **D** key and see if you can bring up the diagnostics. Cheers, Al

Comment: Clarification... first attempt, remove BOTH AC adapter and battery. Second attempt, leave AC power connected. The command-s or D commands should be attempted (separately) at boot time. Cheers, Al

Comment: Shift-Control-Option failed; command-s failed and D-power failed. End result for all three attempts is same as in my original post - backlit laptop screen with no text and external monitor not recognized at all. Interestingly it appears that the laptop screen backlight gets turned on only once Ubuntu starts to load instead of during initial boot process as one would expect with the mac.

Comment: Well, you might have a bad video card, and no apparent way to switch to the other one. Last attempt... boot holding down **command-option-p-r** until it chimes, twice. Cheers, Al

Comment: OK so I have an update... I was finally able to get the external display working through Ubuntu Live (memstick), did a wipe and reinstall of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and now my install provides video through the external display. the drivers being used are nouveau for Nvidia GeForce GT 330M and the i915 driver is being used by the Intel HD graphics card. when I tried installing the proprietary drivers for Nvidia (both 340 and 304) I lost the external monitor. So the graphics cards are not dead (at least not entirely). Any suggestions on the cause or next steps would be appreciated.